# Substitute function for setAlpha on Android 2.3.3?

Tags: android

How would I make this code work for both Android 2.3.3 and 4? I've made a check for version number, but setAlpha is not on 2.3.3, so what can I substitute setAlpha with to get the same effect as below?

```
private void disableButton(boolean isEnable, View v) {
    v.setEnabled(isEnable);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 10) {
        return;
    } else {
        if (isEnable) {
            v.setAlpha(1.0f);
        } else {
            v.setAlpha(0.5f);
        }
    }   
}
```

Thanks.

Edit: To clarify, I do not actually want the function to return when the SDK version is less than 10, I'd like it to do the equivalent of what is in it's else statement (basically when it is above version 10), but since setAlpha is not in versions below 11, I'm unsure of what to do; I just put "return" as a temporary placeholder.

Comment: You can use the NineOldAndroid library, which enables the usage of Honeycomb animations for lower api levels check [this link out](http://nineoldandroids.com/)